# Creating a directive with OnClick function (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

im new to angular and i have been trying for the past half day to figure this out. i'd appreciate to hear what is the best practice for this case since i've tried different approaches to accomplishing this but im not sure which one i should follow.

I have a table where each  contains a directive : 
my-shift has a template :

```
<shift day={{day}} shift={{shift}} status={{status}}>
    <img ng-if="pic==0" ng-src="images\dislikeR.png" class="like">
    <img ng-if="pic==1" ng-src="images\likeR.png" class="like">
    <img ng-if="pic==2" ng-src="images\mehR.png" class="like">
</shift>
```

each  represents a shift request where the value can be 0,1,2
which means "dislike" , "like" and "meh".

i want it so when i click on the element it changes between states 0->1->2
accordingly, changing both the 'status' attribute and the image shown.
the way i've tried so far is by using ng-if as you can see.

how would i add an OnClick function to each instance of the directive ?
This is my attempt, but nothing fires when i click, i tried replacing "this" with "shift" still no luck.

```
MyApp.directive('myShift',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            day: '=',
            shift: '=',
            status: '=',
            pic: "=status"
        },
        templateUrl: "shift.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $(this).click(function(){
                alert("TEST")
                if($scope.pic==2)
                    $scope.pic=0;
                else
                    $scope.pic+=1;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UPDATE :**

Everything works but the picture isnt changing, on click i increment the $scope.status ( it does increment i checked ) however the template doesn't refresh... not sure why, the problem isn't just with ng-if , but a regular expression e,g {{status}} doesnt update either. what could be wrong :|

```
App.directive('myShift',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            day: '=',
            shift: '=',
            status: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "shift.html",

        controller: function($scope, $element) {

            $element.on('click', function(){

                if($scope.status==2){
                    alert($scope.status);
                    $scope.status=0;
                    alert($scope.status);
                }
                else if($scope.status==0){ 
                        alert($scope.status);
                        $scope.status=1;
                        alert($scope.status);
                    }
                    else if($scope.status==1){
                        alert($scope.status);
                        $scope.status=2;
                        alert($scope.status);
                    }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Try $element.on('click', function(){});

Comment: `$scope.pic = $scope.pic +1 % 2` use mod, plus you can use `$element.on('click', function(){})`

Comment: if your directive name is **myShift** then use <my-shift> not <shift>

Comment: In addition to the comments from Tim Dau and Jesús Quintana, the `=` binding does not pair with `status="{{status}}"`, use `status="status"` *or* the `@` binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. $element.on did the trick. however the change to $scope.pic does not seem to effect the template ng-if . the images don't change.

Answer (score 0):

MyApp.directive('myShift',function(){

```
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
        day: '=',
        shift: '=',
        status: '=',
        pic: "=status"
    },
    templateUrl: "shift.html",
    link: function($scope, $element) {
        $element.on('click',function(){
```

// do something hear

```
        });
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

When you make a directive the name given is dash converted to be used in your template:

For example:

- 'shift' is *shift*
- 'myShift' is *my-shift*
- 'myShiftIsAwesome' is *my-shift-is-awesome*

if you understand this , the first change is change the tag from:

```
<shift day={{day}} shift={{shift}} status={{status}}>
```

to

```
<my-shift day={{day}} shift={{shift}} status={{status}}>
```

And the closing one.

The second problem if you gonna use Angular, start forgetting jQuery i recommend to you change the directive to this:

```
MyApp.directive('myShift',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            day: '=',
            shift: '=',
            status: '=',
            pic: "=status"
        },
        templateUrl: "shift.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $element.on('click', function(){
                if($scope.pic==2)
                    $scope.pic=0;
                else
                    $scope.pic+=1;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Tha last one is a recommendation, the original code gonna work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. $element.on did the trick. however the change to $scope.pic does not seem to effect the template ng-if . the images don't change.

Comment: Mmmm maybe this line in scope directive are getting you trouble, pic: "=status", use this instead pic:"="

Comment: Everything works, on click i increment the $scope.status ( it does increment i checked ) however the template doesn't refresh... not sure why, the problem isn't just with ng-if , but a regular expression e,g {{status}} doesnt update either. what could be wrong :|.

Comment: I was thinking maybe you need use $scope.$apply to execute the digest because on.click is not a native angular event

Answer (score 0):

Make `restict` property to 'E' and use `element` instead of `this`

```
MyApp.directive('myShift',function(){

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            day: '=',
            shift: '=',
            status: '=',
            pic: "=status"
        },
        templateUrl: "shift.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $element.click(function(){

            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so using jQuery to assign a listener to the shift element did not work, the solution like 'Jesús Quintana' said was to use a native angular directive. i simply created a $scope.clickMe = function(){..} using the directive controller and applied ng-click="clickMe();" on the on the appropriate tag in the template.
i guess angular is only sensitive to events triggered in the template by angular directives and not regular js.

```
templateUrl: "shift.html",

        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.clickMe = function(){
                if($scope.status==2){
                    alert($scope.status);
                    $scope.status=0;
                    alert($scope.status);
                }
                else if($scope.status==0){ 
                        alert($scope.status);
                        $scope.status=1;
                        alert($scope.status);
                    }
                    else if($scope.status==1){
                        alert($scope.status);
                        $scope.status=2;
                        alert($scope.status);
                    }
            }
```

and my template :

```
<shift xday={{day}} xshift={{shift}} xstatus={{status}} ng-click="clickMe();">

    <img ng-show="status==0" ng-src="images\dislikeR.png" class="like">
    <img ng-show="status==1" ng-src="images\likeR.png" class="like">
    <img ng-show="status==2" ng-src="images\mehR.png" class="like">
</shift><br>
```